# An issue of C in 64 bit architecture: pthread_kill()

Tags: c, 64-bit, pthreads, segmentation-fault, 32bit-64bit

The question is quite simple: my application runs perfectly on a 32 bit architecture, but on a 64 bit arch. I got `segmentation fault`. I guess that the cause is the execution of a `pthread_kill()` call. Is it possible or my supposition is just wrong?

Comment: This is just a wild guess of yours. If you are porting a program to another processor architecture, all kind of things can happen. Run your program in a debugger and look where the segfault comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Here'a a link about the issue of throwing a `segfault` on `pthread_kill` that is caused by invalid `pthread_t` ids: http://udrepper.livejournal.com/16844.html

Answer (score 0):

What operating system and what glibc are you using?

If you're using a mainstream implementation of pthread (say a recent GNU glibc on Linux) I'm quite sure they're not broken.

I think that your crash is likely due to some problem in your code or maybe to an incorrect mixing of 32bit and 64bit binary code.

Could you try to reproduce your crash with as little code lines as possible and paste it here?

Comment: I'm on a Debian GNU/Linux 2.6.26-2-686 kernel version and 2.7 glibc version.

Comment: It is physically impossible to "mix" 32-bit and 64-bit code in the same user-level application on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation fault is almost certainly *not* a result of `pthread_kill()`, but a plain old bug in the application (many bugs show up only in 64-bit compiles, or only with certain memory layouts; nothing special about *your* particular application here).

Instead of *guessing* what the cause *might* be, run your application under `GDB` or `Valgrind`. Both will likely make it painfully clear where your bug is.